# Default Imports work differently between Babel and Typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules

This is perfectly fine for Babel/Webpack

`import React from 'react';`

but in Typescript needs to be:

`import * as React from 'react';`

what's the reason?

Comment: The second is not a default import. Also what is `foo`, how does it export the thing you want to import?

Comment: you use it as default import in babel... (this is how it works for react)

Comment: IIRC, this is a special React.js thing where it exports everything both as named and as a property of the default-exported object. The second one should work fine in Babel as well. I guess TypeScript doesn't like the first because it doesn't match the type declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to your `tsconfig.json` to allow default imports from modules with no default export.

Comment: So you basically mean that Babel allows this by default?

Comment: I think that this started because of babel... Not sure